# What is the meaning of “you should know what the help says on link only answers”?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm a member of stackoverflow. And I find a below comment under a answer posted.

> As a 2year+ member you should know what the help says on link only answers

What do they mean by **you should know what the help says on link only answers**

PS: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035013/6422273) has a link to a quora answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “help” refers to the “help center”. I usually call it the “help center”, not simply the “help”. Answers that simply consist of a link are discouraged. You should include relevant details in your answers along with the link. Here is what the user is referencing:

> #### Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.
>
> *Help Center > [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*

In other words, you should be familiar with this information from the help center since you have been a member for more than 2 years.

Comment: Actually i understand the part "As a 2+ years member you should know **this**". What I was not able to understand is that "this". Now reading again, it clears it out. Thanks.  _I would like to upvote but not enough reputation_

Answer (score 0):

*link-only* answers are those which do not offer content but merely point to an external resource via its URL. These answers contain only a link. An adjective, "link-only", is created to describe that situation.   If a vehicle, let's say a driving lawn mower, has no Reverse gear, it could be said to have a "forward-only" transmission.   If no language other than English is permitted on a site, it could be called an "English-only" site.

**You should know** means "You ought to know".